# How to tag friends in a photo generated by a facebook application?

Tags: facebook, api

I am making an App that can generate a picture with several user's friends.

Now, I want to know how can I tag friends in the photo generated.

Answer (score 0):

via the Graph API, there's a tags property on the photo object that is an array of tags  in which you can specify x/y coordinates as well as a user id for each tag.  See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/

Happy programming!